# feed button for facebook not working

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

$i got the following in JS consol

Error
An error occurred with Sharebutton. Please try later

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

while am putting my configuration as follow

App Display Name:

App Namespace:

Contact Email:

App Domain:
www.somthing.com

------------------------------------js

```
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit= function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '204143816348127', // App ID

      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

function kuky(){

FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
   name: 'Connect',
   caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
      description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
   actions: [
        { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
   ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

191 is usually always because the code is not being run from the domain you have in your app settings.  Also, be sure to include a channelURL in the FB.init() for better performance.